# WiFi hardware issue in Ubuntu

Tags: wireless

My laptop is Lenovo B590 and after installing Ubuntu 20.10 I can't connect WiFi because it says no WiFi adapter found. I recently switched from Windows to Linux (Ubuntu 20.10). Please help me.

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu. Please edit your question and include the output of the `lspci | grep -i net` command so that we know what kind of adapter you have. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest the much more complete: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3`